# "Broken" directory in OSX - what can I do?

Tags: macos, filesystems

There is a directory in my filesystem.  If I do an `ls -a` in the directory, I get nothing (not even `./` and `../`).  If I do an `rmdir`, I get told that the directory is not empty.  `rm -rf` gives the same "not empty" error.  I tried to use `mv` to change its name.  This produced an `Input/output error`, but was apparently successful.

Say that I don't care about the contents, I just want to clean it up.  What can I do?

OSX Tiger, in a FileVault home directory (if it matters).

EDIT: more diagnostics, as suggested by gbarry.  As I said, the `mv` was apparently successful, so the directory is called `foo` now.

```
$ ls -ld foo
drwxr-xr-x   3 repton  repton  102B May 30  2007 foo/
$ stat foo
234881029 39016 drwxr-xr-x 3 repton repton 0 102 "Jul  9 12:00:10 2009" "May 30 03:24:34 2007" "Jan 21 16:55:53 2008" 4096 0 0 foo
$ file foo
foo: directory
$ du -h foo
  0B    foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tiger, a FileVault disk is a sparse image. (After upgrading to Leopard it's still such [sparse image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_image), but when creating a new FileVault in Leopard, you'll get a sparse *bundle* instead. The latter works better with Time Machine.)

Did you try to run Disk Utility on that image? See Apple's [Mac OS X 10.3, 10.4: FileVault - How to verify or repair a home directory image](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2631) for detailed instructions. (Or, if for some reason you cannot use that, maybe [`hdiutil verify`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/hdiutil.1.html).)

Comment: I will have a go with Disk Utility later today (I need to use the computer right now).  What does `hdiutil attach` do?

Comment: It mounts the disk image, and then by default verifies it. In fact, I guess one could better use `hdiutil verify` instead (I'll change my answer). But: no need for any of those command line commands if you're trying Disk Utility.

Comment: I followed the instructions on that Apple page.  When I tried to open the `.sparseimage`, OSX said it was damaged and opening it might break my system :-/ so I made a copy (65GB over the network.. ugh.) and then opened it.  No trouble.  Disk repair fixed some issues.  I had some trouble resetting the permissions (changing the ownership of my home directory back to my username wouldn't "stick", until I tried setting to my username, then back to admin, then back to my username again), but all seems well now, and the directory is working again.  Thanks.

Comment: Good it was solved. Too bad one still needs some kind of sysadmin skills to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

Before deleting, ask it how much is being used (since it's "not empty").  Be careful it isn't like a link to the root directory or something.

Is the name of the directory reasonable or is it blank or funny characters?  Also try other commands to describe it.  ls -ld funnydir , stat funnydir , and file funnydir should all tell you "it's a directory".

If there's really something wrong, an fsck or equivalent "check the directory structure" command might fix it (as you can see I don't know much about OS X proper yet).

Comment: See my post edit.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to repair the hard drive using the Disk Utility. I had a similar problem with one file staying in trash even after forcing it to empty (the system kept saying it was in use). After repairing the disk I was able to delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling FileVault, deleting the directory, and re-enabling FileVault?

FileVault might not be able to decrypt the directory on-the-fly (for whatever reason), so you're able to see it, but not do anything with it. Disabling FileVault will force it to batch-decrypt everything, allowing the OS to directly access the disk.

Comment: I have not ... but I've got 60GB in here, so that seems like a process that will take a long time.  I'll give it a try if no one else comes up with an idea (maybe overnight in stages).